# Can a furnace light things on fire?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a room where the 1-block-thick roof is covered in furnaces as combination cheap blast protection from creepers above and fast processing for ores/glass etc.  I'm considering doing some floor-to-ceiling wool block patterns, but this would jut the wool up against some furnaces and I need to make sure I won't be setting my room ablaze.  **Can furnaces light things on fire, particularly wool?**  I'm inclined to believe not but I'd like to know for sure before risking it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, furnaces do not start fires

The fire effect from one is purely visual.

Comment: somehow my crafting table caught on fire the furnace was right next to it

Comment: Did you have a flint and steel in your hand by any chance?

Comment: Lava nearby will also start fires. Furnaces and torches do not, however.

Comment: I remember furnaces really worked as lava in the previous comment, but currently it seems not to.

Answer (score 11):

No, they cannot. You can safely place your furnace near wool, wood, or anything else flammable and it cannot catch on fire.

In the same vein, torches, while 'on fire' graphically, do not start or spread fire.